# Code for UIPasteboard?

Tags: xcode, uipasteboard

Is there a way to place this code in a `UIPasteboard`?

```
[TEXTFeild setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];

UIImageView *imageView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 22, 22)];
imageView1.image = image;
TEXTFeild.leftView = imageView1;
```

Comment: You mean for pasting in some textfield or textview etc? Sure why not, make it a string.

Comment: I just started programming, so how would you do this?

Comment: Just make the whole code into a string.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, may I ask why you want to paste code into UIPasteboard?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, thats why i'm asking for help.

Comment: I want to paste an image into a UIPasteboard, but i want it to be a certain size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To share an image to pasteboard use this :

```
//Method 1
UIImage * image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"FILE_PATH"];
UIPasteboard * pasteboard=[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard setImage:image];

//Method 2
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[pasteboard setData:imageData forPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypePNG];
```

and to scale the image before pasting:

```
CGFloat image_max_height = 1080;
CGFloat image_max_width = 1080;

UIImage *finalImage = image;

if (image.size.width>image_max_width || image.size.height>image_max_height) {
    finalImage = [image imageByScalingAspectFitSize:CGSizeMake(image_max_width, image_max_height)];
}
```

This code scales the image down to 1080px x 1080px if its greater that 1080x1080.

**Update :** The method is from a UIImage category called [UIImage+SimpleResize](https://github.com/robertmryan/AnimateMasks/tree/master/AnimateMasks/UIImage%2BSimpleResize). Add it to your project and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Please delete the duplicate question.

Comment: Do you have to declare something for "imageByScalingAspectFitSize" to work?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. Just quickly do you have any idea why the image doesn't change size in messages etc?